# Finding boundaries of multiple subsequences in a string

Tags: regex, string, algorithm, subsequence

Given a string of length `n` composed of combinations of `A B D` characters.

Ex-1: `AAAABAAAADADDDDADDDBBBBBBDDDDA`

`Threshold` of `x`, a given substring can contain any other contiguous substring of max length `x`

Ex-2: for a subsequence of `A` in Ex-1, `AAAABAAAADA` is legal substring with (1,11) boundaries for threshold of `x = 2`.

Similarly I want to extract substrings of `A` and `D` separately, ignoring `B` from the main string. There can be many substrings of each type in the main string.

Model Output:

```
Type Boundaries
A    1,11
D    12,20
D    26,29
```

I implemented a in-efficient non-algorithmic way by finding distance between `A`s, if the distance greater than the threshold break the string. I had to run this separately for `A` and `D`. which causes to overlap of the boundary regions.

Can I have a better approach of solving this ?

**EDIT-1**

A legal substring can be of any length, but it should not be contaminated by other substrings larger than threshold `x`. which means while searching for a substring of `A` it should not have other characters `B` or `D` contiguously larger than threshold.

If `x = 2` while searching for `A`, `AABBAAAA, AABDAAAA` are valid, but not `AADBDAAA, AABBBAAA`. Similarly while searching for D(`A` and `B` will be contaminator).

**EDIT-2** Implementation using  "Pham Trung" answer

Code:

```
start = 0
lastA = -1
lastD = -1
x = 2

arr = ["A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "D", "A", "D", "D", "D", "D", "A", "D", "D", "D", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "D", "D", "D", "D", "A"]

for i in range(0, len(arr)):
    if(arr[i] == 'A'):
        if(lastA != -1 and i - lastA > x):
            print("A", start + 1, lastA + 1)
            start = i
        lastA = i
    elif(arr[i] == 'D'):
        if(lastD != -1 and i - lastD > x):
            print("D", start + 1, lastD + 1)
            start = i
        lastD = i
```

Output:

```
A 1 11
D 16 19
A 26 16
```

Code fails to extract substring after `1st` substring.

Comment: It is very hard to understand your question. Does the question mean that we need to find all substring , in which, the distance between each character `A` (or `D`) is not larger than threshold `x`?

Comment: Substring can be of any length, but it cannot be contaminated by other substrings larger than threshold. Ex: AAABBAAA is valid but, AAABBBAAA is not valid for threshold 2.

Comment: Why? I still don't see how number 2 is related here?

Comment: Because second substring AAABBBAAA has 3 B characters in the middle of large `A` substring.

Comment: So, do you mean that the **distance** between each identical character is not larger than 2?

Comment: yes. cannot be larger than threshold.

Comment: For type `D`, is the substring (1, 20) valid for threshold 2, in your example?

Comment: No.  it has more than 2 contiguous A

Comment: So the type A, D or smt doesn't have any meaning?

Comment: They are related to proteins amino-acid properties. I will have to chop the sequence into multiple blocks and use each block separately.

Comment: Post the algorithm you have created so far.

Comment: [llink](https://github.com/VAR121/IDR_Work/blob/master/D_O_block_3.py), input comes from a file. One character per line. Instead A/B/D, I have D/O/N in the input

Answer (score 1):

So, here are some suggestions for your problem:

As we only have three type of characters in our string, thus, it is easy to keep track of the last position of those characters.

Start from the beginning of the string, keep track of what is the distance between the current character and its last position, if it is larger than the threshold, break it and start the new substring from there.

Pseudo code:

```
int start = 0;
int lastA = -1;
int lastD = -1;
for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
    if(input.charAt(i) == 'A'){
       if(lastA != -1 && i - lastA > x){
           create a substring from start to i - 1; 
           start = i; //Update the new start for the next substring
           lastD = -1;//Reset count for D
       }
       lastA = i;
    }else if(input.charAt(i) == 'D'){
       //Do similar to what we do for character A
    } 
}
create a substring from start to end of the string; //We need to add the last substring.
```

Update python code:

```
start = 0
lastA = -1
lastD = -1
x = 2

arr = ["A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "D", "A", "D", "D",    "D","D", "A", "D", "D", "D", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "D", "D", "D", "D", "A"]

for i in range(0, len(arr)):
    if(arr[i] == 'A'):
        if(lastA != -1 and i - lastA > x):
            print("A", start + 1, lastA + 1)
            start = lastA + 1
            while(start < len(arr) and arr[start] == 'B'):
                start = start + 1
            lastD = -1 
        lastA = i
    elif(arr[i] == 'D'):
        if(lastD != -1 and i - lastD > x):
            print("D", start + 1, lastD + 1)
            start = lastD + 1
            while(start < len(arr) and arr[start] == 'B'):
                start = start + 1
            lastA = -1
        lastD = i
while(start < len(arr) and arr[start] == 'B'):
    start = start + 1 
if(start < len(arr)):   
   print("A or D", start + 1, len(arr))
```

Comment: I am using `python`, can also use `perl`

Comment: @aravindramesh just give you some suggestion. Do you understand the idea? is that help or you need smt else?

Comment: I understood it, translating it to python, will post the results.

Comment: Please look at the Edit-2, there should be a "D" block starting from 12, but as `i - lastD` fails, it is not able to enter if.

Comment: @aravindramesh sorry, there are some errors in my pseudo-code. Please take a look at [this](http://ideone.com/1ulUe6). I also update my pseudo-code.

Comment: In the output, 1st block is from 1-15, it should be 1-11,  From 12th position `D` block starts.

Comment: @aravindramesh why? I don't see such restriction in your question? so each substring can only contains either A or D, but not both? I don't think so, as your first example also contains both A and D. Please be more specific and concise about your problem.

Comment: yes, substring can only contain either A or D, not both. if they are present, it should be less than threshold as a substring. Sorry if there is any misunderstanding.

Comment: @aravindramesh ok, let me revise my solution.